# How can I change AspxGridView mode on server side

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I want to change AspxGridView mode on server side. For example :

```
   if( some clauses)
   {
     // Mode is : New row
   }
   else if (some clauses)
   {
     // Mode is : Edit row
   }
```

Do you have any idea?

KR,

Çağın

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call either StartEdit method (to begin editing a certain row) or AddNewRow method.  All gridView members are described in the [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewMembersTopicAll) available online.